# Radical extension and characteristic of underlying field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension such that $F$ contains a primitive root of unity of order the degree of $K/F$. A theorem states that if the characteristic of $F$ is $0$ and $Gal(K/F)$ is a solvable group, then $K/F$ is a radical extension (not necessarily simple).

**Question**: what happens if we don't assume that the characteristic of $F$ is $0$? i.e if $K/F$ is a finite field extension, with $char(F)=p$, such that $F$ contains a primitive root of unity of order $[K:F]$ (which cannot be prime though). If $Gal(K/F)$ is solvable, does it follow that $K/F$ is radical?

Comment: This is false as stated. Did you omit a condition asserting that the Galois group of the Galois closure is solvable?

Comment: I've edited, thanks!

Comment: Now also posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252202/radical-extension-and-characteristic-of-underlying-field (but gathering close votes there).

Comment: Now deleted from MO by OP, after it was closed.